# sbt issues with my ClassBuilder implementation (Scala)

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, runtime

What is Intellij doing for me that sbt isn't?

I am working on a Scala project for which I'd like to support user-defined plugin classes. I've implemented a subclass of ClassLoader:

```
class PluginLoader(directory: String) extends ClassLoader {

  override def findClass(className: String): Class[_] = {
    val bytes = loadClassData(className)
    defineClass(className,bytes,0,bytes.length)
  }

  def loadClassData(className: String): Array[Byte] = {
    val fileName = className.replace('.',File.separatorChar) + ".class"
    val file = new File(directory,fileName)
    val bytes = new Array[Byte](file.length.toInt)
    val inputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))
    inputStream.readFully(bytes)
    inputStream.close()
    bytes
  }
}
```

and I call this with user-defined directory and name of a pre-compiled scala class:

```
new PluginLoader(directory).loadClass(className).newInstance()
```

`findClass` appears to succeed at finding the class the user provides. However, it is then called again looking for `scala.runtime.java8.JFunction2$mcIII$sp.class`. It looks in the user-provided directory, so it cannot find the loaded class.

Here's the error I get: `(run-main-0) java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./scala/runtime/java8/JFunction2$mcIII$sp.class (No such file or directory)`

I have successfully run this application in Intellij, which makes me think I am missing some configuration in sbt, and Intellij is catching my mistake for me.

Do I need to do additional configuration? Should I be loading in an entire jar file instead of just passing a class file?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile a class - not only Scala class, Java class as well - then it not necessarily mean that you will get a single `.class` file.

Internal classes, lambdas/closures, etc will result with additional bytecode, that is required to run, and which doesn't live in the same file as your "original" class.

As far as I can tell here Java created some class because it is the body of some lambda, and you did not loaded it.

Bottom line is: you'd better load everything. IntelliJ might have simply passed a whole classpath to JVM, so your classloader might not have even used your extensions (though you'd have to attach debugger in order to be sure).

Comment: Thanks. I've gone ahead and loaded a jar file assembled with sbt-assembly. I'm now getting a different problem:

`java.lang.ClassCastException <myClass>$$Lambda$4456/762142833 cannot be cast to scala.Function2`